# Is saying, "This is funnier too" incorrect?

Tags: sentence

Regardless of context, is the sentence itself correct? What I said was something along the lines of, "This is smarter, and it is funnier too."

Comment: Yes it is correct syntax

Comment: funny --> funnier --> the funniest. An absolutely correct sentence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Apparently my friend thought the usage of "too" here was incorrect, and I really couldn't see how!

Comment: I wasn't sure where your uncertainty lied. But tell your friend he was mistaken. :)

Comment: and @mplungjan *too*.

Comment: Hahaha, [I see what you did there!](http://i177.photobucket.com/albums/w220/Davis_Andrews/what-you-did-there-i-see-it.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is grammatical, and it is correct too.